# No resource found that matches the given name @style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm going to migrate to android studio.

now,I would like to import this lib :

https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager

after download it, I imported it on the android studio :

> file => import module => Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager directory.

now, I get this error :

> No resource found that matches the given name
>   '@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar'.

[image]

Comment: Do you have `appcompat-v7` in your `dependencies`?

Comment: oh yes, I added it and solved that error, now I get this error :  No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.

Comment: Is your `compileSdkVersion` set to 21 or higher?

Comment: after set it on 21 solved my problem !! but I get this error  :(   : Error:(6, 40) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'homeAsUpIndicator' with value '@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_dark').

Answer (score 0):

By default,this library not support appcompat-v7 21.

To solve this problem, try to do this :

In *TransparentTheme* style:

```
remove: <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>
add: <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

Add this toolbar at the end of the *activity_main.xml* but inside the main root FrameLayout. Of course you can tweak it

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then, in the *MainActivity.java*:

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TextView title;
private ImageView icon;
```

In onCreate method, after setContentView, add:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
```

Replace getActionBarIconView method with this one:

```
private ImageView getActionBarIconView() {
    return icon;
}
```

Replace setTitleAlpha method with this one:

```
private void setTitleAlpha(float alpha) {
    mAlphaForegroundColorSpan.setAlpha(alpha);
    mSpannableString.setSpan(mAlphaForegroundColorSpan, 0, mSpannableString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    title.setText(mSpannableString);
}
```

**source:**

https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager/issues/9